# Solving $\cos(3\pi x) = \frac12\log_7 x$

Tags: logarithms

I came across a high school math question which asks to find how many real numbers $x$ satisfy the equation
$$\cos(3\pi x) = \frac12\log_7 x$$

I have no clue how to solve it with both $\cos$ and $\log$ coexist in an equation.

I used an online program to plot both graphs and, in theory, I could count all the intersections exist between $-1 \le y \le +1$ (since that's the limit of $\cos (3\pi x)$). I trust there must be a smarter way to compute this?

Comment: You are almost certainly meant to solve this problem with computer assistance, in the form of looking at a graph.  Edit: upon further thought, there will be many zeros, and you'll need to use the periodicity of the cosine function to do some smart counting on the interval where $ 1/2 log_7(x) $ is between $ -1 $ and $ 1 $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've highlighted the region between $ x = 1 $ and $ x = 48 $ where you do not need to *count* the roots - you can simply use the fact that sinusoid curve will pass through the logarithm curve twice per period.  Since the period is $ P = 2/3 $, there will be approximately 141 roots in that interval.  Near the boundary of the region I highlighted, you will need to use a graphing calculator to count the intersections.
[image]

If we zoom in on the left boundary we see this:
[image]

and if we zoom in on the right boundary we see this:
[image]

By this reasoning I count 3 roots in [0,1], 141 roots in [1,48], and 3 roots in [48,49].  Beyond $ x = 49 $, the logarithm curve leaves the range of the sinusoid, so there will be no more roots.  So by my count, I see 147 roots.